# Core Data Crashing When Pushing to View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

So this is my first time working with core data, and so far it hasn't been the best experience. My application so far consists of two UITableView controllers and a single ViewController. The app simply asks the user to enter the name of a list on UIAlert and it saves to core data, and the name of the list is put into the first tableview. So far so good. Then the user clicks on the name of the list and it pushes them to the contents on the list, which is empty because it hasn't been populated yet. So my problem is when I go to populate it my app just crashes. I don't even get to the the ViewController. I'm really lost I'll put the necessary code here if there's any more let me know. Thanks!

Error `argv char ** 0xbfffeda8  0xbfffeda8`

Data Model:

[image]

The .m To Add Items to the list:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newItem setValue:self.name.text forKey:@"itemName"];
    [newItem setValue:self.price.text forKey:@"price"];
    [newItem setValue:self.desc.text forKey:@"description"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

The .m to show all the items in a list:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the lists from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Item"];
    self.lists = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    self.items = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[item valueForKey:@"itemName"]];

    return cell;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove device from table view
        [self.items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}




#pragma mark - Segue

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedItem = [self.items objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        AddViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.items = selectedItem;
    }
}

@end
```

And the .m displaying all the lists:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the lists from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"List"];
    self.lists = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    self.items = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.lists.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *list = [self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[list valueForKey:@"name"]];

    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add List" message:@"Create a New Wish List" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [alert setTag:2];
    [alert show];
    alert.delegate = self;
}
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != 0 && alertView.tag == 2) {
        UITextField *tf = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        // Create a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newList = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newList setValue:tf.text forKey:@"name"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);


        }

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"List"];
    self.lists = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    self.items = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove list from table view
        [self.lists removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: You have a few issues here, I've tried to cover a number in my answer, but it would be good to see an image of your data model too...

Comment: Added one. Thanks I'm really confused.

Comment: Ok, reworded my answer a little. Basically, list controller should concentrate on list and do nothing with items. And item controller should be passed a list and use the items from the relationship.

Comment: Still having this issue, if anyone has a solution I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to make your life easier, and your app more efficient.

This is incorrect:

```
self.lists = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
self.items = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

because these sets should contain different types of entity instance. But, you don't actually need `self.items`. The model contains a relationship between `List` and `Item` and you should just get the items for a specified list using that relationship (or a fetch request using the relationship) when you need it. And remove `self.items`, it's just confusing you. In the list view controller you don't need the items anyway.

When you push to show the items, you should be getting the selected `List` and passing that. So where you have `destViewController.items = selectedItem;` you should have something like `destViewController.list = selectedList;`, and then the item controller uses the relationship again to display the appropriate items.

And, when you add a new item, you have to associated it with `self.list`:

```
[newItem setValue:self.list forKey:@"list"];
```

You should also use managed object subclasses, and the best way to manage them is by using [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator).

Aside: Where you have `if ([delegate performSelector:` it should be `if ([delegate respondsToSelector:`, and probably log if you don't get a context back...

Comment: I'm still really lost, I tried what you told me and I'm not having any luck, I also generated Managed Object Subclasses. I just don't know what to do.

Comment: It still crashes when I try and add an item to a list. I changed `destViewController.items = selectedItem;` and removed `self.items = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];` I also generated managed object subclasses.

Comment: what is the line that it crashes on? Have you debugged to check what each of the variables there is set to?

Comment: It's crashing on line 16 of main.m. This is what the console prints out: `argc = (int) 3` and `argv = (char **) 0xbfffee08`

Comment: I never changed it: `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`

Comment: that isn't really where the exception is. Add an all exception breakpoint

Comment: I did that. It's doing the same thing.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `save:`, first line, then step through each line

Comment: Did that, same issue.

Comment: You said it crashes when you save the new `Item`, yes? So it should get to the start of the `save:` method. If not, then you need to scatter breakpoints all over (and I guess you're referencing a deallocated instance somewhere, so turning on zombies may help)

Comment: No it crashes when I go push to add a new item.

Comment: I can't even get to the view to add the item.

Comment: ok, so probably breakpoint in prepare for segue and another when you trigger the segue

Comment: Ok I added a breakpoint on `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` and I got this: `self=(WishListView*) 0x8adeeb0` `segue=(UIStoryboardModalSegue*)0xde6b5b0` `sender=(UIBarButtonItem*)0x8aded30`

Comment: but it didn't hit prepare for segue? Then presumably the segue identifier is spelt wrong

Comment: I may have fixed it I re-did the whole view and .m for the AddItem. And I'm now successfully pushing to the view. Just have to see if it saves :D Thanks for your help and pacientes, I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Ok I fixed it, but now I have a new issue, when I hit save It crashes. I get the same error and all that too. So we are pretty much back to where we started. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is what I get after I added the breakpoint.                `self=(AddViewController *) 0x8b1dca0 
sender=(UIButton *) 0x8b1fdd0 
context=(NSManagedObjectContext *)0x8e11a90 
newItem=(Item_Item_ *)0xa116be0`

Comment: That isn't exception information. You need the exception type, message and stack trace to understand what's happening. Read the Xcode user guide on debugging